# clearing port in use manually vs waiting 60 seconds

Tags: networking, port, licenses

running `lmgrd` which is a license manager executable that comes with paid-for software, in a work environment.

I often resort to `kill -9 <pid>` of existing `lmgrd` processes found by doing `ps -ef | grep lmgrd` when I have trouble restarting an *lmgrd* license manager.

If within ~60 seconds of trying to start lmgrd, via `lmgrd -c <license_file> -L <log file>` it will respond with an error stating *port number still in use* for the port number that's specified in my license file.

Is there a way I can manually *clear* that port in use?  So I can immediately start `lmgrd` again versus waiting 60 seconds like I've been doing for linux to clear it automatically or however linux does it?

*I don't wanna have to wait for the OS to clear the port, ain't got time for that.*

```
# output from lmgrd log file

10:37:41 (lmgrd) Server's System Date and Time: Tue Mar 01 2022 10:37:41 EST
10:37:41 (lmgrd) SLOG: Summary LOG statistics is enabled.
10:37:56 (lmgrd) The TCP port number in the license, 1999, is already in use.
10:37:56 (lmgrd) Possible causes:
10:37:56 (lmgrd)    1) The license server manager (lmgrd) is already running for this license.
10:37:56 (lmgrd)    2) The OS has not "cleared" this port since lmgrd died.
10:37:56 (lmgrd)    3) Another process is using this port number (unlikely).
10:37:56 (lmgrd) Solutions:
10:37:56 (lmgrd)    1) Make sure lmgrd and all vendor daemons for this
10:37:56 (lmgrd)       license are not running.
10:37:56 (lmgrd)    2) You may have to wait for the OS to clear this port.
10:37:56 (lmgrd) Retrying for about 5 more minutes
10:38:14 (lmgrd) Still trying...
```

Comment: Don't kill with `-9`, check what other signals it accepts and only use `SIGKILL` if you really need to. Second, go back to the publishers and complain, if I remember correctly, they should be using the `SO_REUSEPORT` option.

Comment: I'll never stop using kill -9

Comment: ( @Bib actually it's SO_REUSEADDR). Not sure that's enough. The mere fact of the local side closing established connections first, will trigger the TIME-WAIT state. That's something defined in RFC 793 (year 1981): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.5 . Here `(2 MSL)` is this delay (which was probably longer originally). What's the system OS? Special tweaks might depend on the OS. Also if you ensure lmgrd isn't handling any connection when killed, then it shouldn't get a blocked port.

Comment: RHEL 7.9 x86-64

Comment: @A.B I looked at them both, and picked the wrong one as usual. Actually, this is the correct method, it allows the socket to be reopened with tuples still semi-active. It's what I've done in the past and I am sure just about every decent software uses it. Can you imagine killing apache then having to wait? And indeed, from the apache2 source... `httpd-2.4.52/CHANGES: *) fcgistarter: Specify SO_REUSEADDR to allow starting a server with old connections in TIME_WAIT.  [Jeff Trawick]`